# Laravel carbon createFromFormat adding 1 year

Tags: php, laravel-4

I´m trying to use carbon for use diffInMinutes, that works great,
but before I do this I convert my timestamp in carbon format 
I do:

```
$teste= '2014-12-12 15:00:00';

$entrada = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:m:s', $teste);
```

but when I dd($teste, $entrada):

```
string '2014-12-12 15:00:00' (length=19)

object(Carbon\Carbon)[340]
  public 'date' => string '2013-12-12 15:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Sao_Paulo' (length=17)
```

anyone knows how fix this???
thx in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this is the issue but your date format should be

```
'Y-m-d H:i:s' not 'Y-m-d H:m:s'
```

[Date format reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Comment: Happy to be of some help

Comment: @user3193744 you should accept the answer, as Demo put some effort into it.